# How to insert print for each function of C language for debugging?

Tags: c, debugging

I am studying and debugging one software. There are thousands of functions in this software. I plan to add printf() at the entry and exit point of each function. It will take a lot of time.
Is there one tool/script to do this?
I may use '__cyg_profile_func_enter'. But it can only get address. But I have to run another script to get function name. I also hope to get value of input parameters of this function too.

Comment: If you're trying to build a coverage test, [gcov](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html) may be what you want.

Comment: please add more specifics into your question. The version of the compiler etc, platform. `cyg` would point to cygwin?

Comment: Gcc 4.8.5 is used. '__cyg_profile_func_enter' is function called when GCC option 'finstrument-functions' is used.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to AOP : Aspect Oriented Programming. Personnaly I've only tried with Java and Spring AOP but there's an API for C too : AspectC (https://sites.google.com/a/gapp.msrg.utoronto.ca/aspectc/home). From what I've seen, it's not the only one.

From what I've red about this library, you can add an pointcut before compiling with AspectC :

```
// before means it's a before function aspect
// call means it's processed when a function is called
// args(...) means it applies to any function with any arguments
// this->funcName is the name of the function handled by AspectC
before(): call(args(...)) {
  printf("Entering %s\n", this->funcName);
}
```

(not tried by myself but extracted from the reference page https://sites.google.com/a/gapp.msrg.utoronto.ca/aspectc/tutorial)

This is only a basic overview of what can be done and you still have to deal with the compilation (documented in the page linked before) but it looks like it could possibly help you. Give a try with a simple POC maybe.